# Formatter in JdateChooser

Tags: java, swing, simpledateformat, jcalendar

I am using JDateChooser from jcalendar-1.2.2 jar. I have set dateformatString as "yyyyMMdd".By default it is showing today's date September 1, 2010. whenever I try to change the date it is displayed correctly in yyyyMMdd format. How to set default format for default date (todate).

Comment: It would really, really help if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Just the most basic UI that shows the issue.

Comment: JCalendar.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("Xx.Xx.Xxxx")); or to setLocale(new Locale("Xxxxxxx")), Im sure that here is manz posts about, note all docs, demos, resources about JCalendar aren't accesible, url server is down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to get ?

```
    public class TestJFrame extends JFrame {

        /**
         *
         */
        public TestJFrame() {

        //set test frame 
            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

             //make a date chooser 
            JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
            //set date format 
            dateChooser.setDateFormatString("yyyyMMdd");
            //set date 
            dateChooser.setDate(new Date());

            //add to test frame 
            getContentPane().add(dateChooser);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);

        }

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new TestJFrame();

        }
    }
```

It may help you find what's wrong.